# Is there any build tool like maven in racket?

Tags: racket

I'm from java world and enthusiasm with Racket.
Want to know is where a tools similar as Maven position.If you not family with Maven, there are SBT in Scala, gradle in Android, mix in Elixir, etc, as build tool.
Specify, I need the feature to define a project:
1. manage dependencies.
2. build to library(which is called package in racket).
3. build to executable app.

I have try with `raco` which has many features include build to library or to executable app and install a directory as a local package.

**What I want to achieve is manage dependencies from a package central repository.**
`raco pkg install` can't defined in a project file like `pom.xml`

Thanks a lot.

#### Update

There is a tool called [PLaneT](https://docs.racket-lang.org/planet/Using_PLaneT.html#%28part._finding-a-package%29) could define `require` package which from a central repository but official website called it as `old package system`.
New package system in [here](http://pkgs.racket-lang.org/), but not find any feature like or could replace PLaneT.

Answer (score 3):

The package repository for Racket is here:

```
http://pkgs.racket-lang.org/
```

The Racket philosophy is not to have external tools, but embed
build information into the program. There is a tool to download and
install packages though -- it is called `raco`. See the Racket
docs for more information on `raco`.

If you prefer a more graphical approach, try out the package manager in DrRacket.

Comment: thanks.I can define deps in info.rkt with raco but how to auto download dependencies from central repository? After all, I can't say to my team members "Hi guys, download package in which `info.rkt` deps shows with `raco pkg install` if you not install yet".

Comment: When you install a package with dependencies, raco prompts you to install the packages it depends on. So it sounds like the thing you want is already there?